# Upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 - Proftpd with sftp stopped working

Tags: 18.04, sftp, proftpd

I made an upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 about an hour ago.
On 17.10 proftpd with TLS and SFTP runs perfekt.

After the Update, Filezilla and WinSCP stopped working with SFTP-Connections, TLS is still working.
Filezilla shows:

```
Befehl: open "user@server" 1111
Error:  Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

I still can connect with putty/ssh with login and ssh-key.

It's all in the same LAN.

As it's a VM-Machine, i made a snapshot bevore the Update and made the procedure twice with the same result.

I could not find any solution via Google, but installing SFTP with VSFTP.

Best regards for any hint!

MrMister

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I've filed a ticket here:
https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/issues/789

The same set up works great on Ubuntu 16.
I think it has to do with the openssl library